# mac os 10.6 server: crontab does not fire wget script

Tags: macos, cron, wget

I am completely baffled by the behaviour of cron under Mac OS 10.6 Server. I am trying to run two scripts in a cronjob like this:

```
00 16 * * * /Users/myusername/script.sh
04 16 * * * /Users/myusername/crontest.sh
```

While 'script.sh' contains a wget command:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -r -l3 --no-parent -nc -A ".shtml" 'http://some.url/somethingelse/'
```

'crontest.sh' contains just a test script:

```
echo "hi" >> /Users/myusername/crontest.txt
```

Problem is, 'script.sh' does not fire, but 'crontest.sh' does. What could be the cause of the wget script not firing? Do the scripts require a specific encoding? Does cron write a log file somewhere?

(I tested the wget command by itself in the shell, where it works fine.)

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron runs scripts with a very minimal environment.  In particular, its PATH doesn't contain all of the usual binaries directories, just /usr/bin and /bin, so any commands in other binaries directories (like wget) will not be available.

There are several ways to fix this.  One option is to have your script give the complete path of wget:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/bin/wget -r -l3 --no-parent -nc -A ".shtml" 'http://some.url/somethingelse/'
```

(or whatever its actual path is -- use `which wget` to find out.)

Another is to explicitly set PATH in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
wget -r -l3 --no-parent -nc -A ".shtml" 'http://some.url/somethingelse/'
```

(or whatever PATH you normally use; be sure it includes wget's location.)

Or you can set the PATH in your crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
00 16 * * * /Users/myusername/script.sh
04 16 * * * /Users/myusername/crontest.sh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first way works fine. Am I just blind or is this rarely mentioned in cron tutorials/FAQs??

Comment: The [top google hit for `cron faq`](http://216.147.18.102/unixfaq/cron.shtml) does mention this issue in the troubleshooting section (along with some other common gotchas), but that's the only one of the pages I looked through that mentions it.  It should probably be more widely documented, as it's a fairly common problem when setting up cron entries.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with this for over a week.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking the obvious: Execute flag and permissions set the same on both scripts?

Comment: Yes, they are set to the same settings, and both are executable scripts.

Comment: And did you execute script.sh in the shell or the wget command it contains?

Comment: I tested both, the script and the wget command contained in the script; both work fine outside of cron.

Comment: Oh, are you saving the output from the wget anywhere in your script?

Comment: Sorry, to be more precise, what user account does the cron daemon execute your command as, and where would it save the files wget fetches? Would it be worth doing a chdir before the call to wget and see if the files show up then?

Comment: cron executes the command using my own user, as verified by checking the file /usr/lib/cron/tabs/myusername. I therefore assume wget output would show up in my home directory; is this right?

Comment: I would try specifying the output directory explicitly, or turn on wget logging and store the log in a known file, that way you can assure it was executed too.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider making the leap to launchd. As a long-time Unix person, I initially found launchd annoyingly complex, but now that I've been using it, I find the rich feature set to be superior to trusty ole cron.